# Cannot push to file based repository

Tags: git

I get "The remote end hung up unexpectedly" when I try to push to a file based repository.

Step to recreate:

```
git init --bare hello.git  
git clone hello.git  
cd hello  
cat>temp.txt  
Hello world  
ctrl+z  
git add .  
git commit  
git push
```

This is happening on Windows 7 with Git 1.9.2.msysgit.0
How can I push to a file based repository?

The config file in hello.git:

```
[core]  
repositoryformatversion = 0  
filemode = false  
bare = true  
symlinks = false  
ignorecase = true  
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
```

Comment: I've tried your commands on mac and `push` works as expected. Might be a windows issue. What do you have in `hello/.git/config` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to push finally using the following:

```
git push origin master
```

The error message from Git wasn't clear enough for me. I guess since I cloned a bare repo, Git couldn't find a matching or a common branch between the clone and bare repo. So I had tell Git explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see that you went somewhere else in the directory tree before cloning.

It does not make sense to have a bare repository right inside the clone of that bare repository. Move somewhere else in the directory tree and try cloning again.

File based clones are no different from any other communication channel, so push generally works. But it does not work with one repository on top of the other.

You might want to only have a local git repository. This is easily done:

```
git init
... add files
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
...done
```

You would only push if you have a second repository, but you don't need a bare repository for your work, only as a shared target for you and your companions to exchange commits (if you don't have a Github/Bitbucket account to work with). A bare repository does not have a working copy, i.e. you cannot checkout a branch or commit and see the files that are in this commit. You'd only be able to see the internal data structures of Git

Comment: The bare repo doesn't exist inside the clone. Bare is under c:/hello.git and the clone is c:/hello . I get the same error even if the bare and clone are in different directories like bare in c:/temp/hello.git and the clone in c:/clones/hello. I wanted to create a bare repository so I can simulate a 3 way merge by creating 2 clones of the bare and make pushes from clone with conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that your bare repository was empty when you cloned it. `git` should have warned you about this when you issued `git clone`. When you subsequently committed to the new repository, you created a branch `master` in the clone that did not exist in the bare repository. Consequently, when you tried to push that commit to the upstream repository, git could not find a branch corresponding to the one you tried to push, and aborted.

Admittedly, the error message is a bit misleading and anything but helpful...